# No axis shown in Xcode 7 playground

Tags: swift, xcode7, swift-playground, xcplayground

I try to plot sin wave in Xcode 7 playground. I have the following code (got from [this post](https://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/rapid-prototyping-in-swift-playgrounds/)):

```
import XCPlayground

let sineArraySize = 64

let frequency1 = 4.0
let phase1 = 0.0
let amplitude1 = 2.0
let sineWave = (0..<sineArraySize).map {
    amplitude1 * sin(2.0 * M_PI / Double(sineArraySize) * Double($0) * frequency1 + phase1)
}

func plotArrayInPlayground<T>(arrayToPlot:Array<T>, title:String) {
    for currentValue in arrayToPlot {
        XCPCaptureValue(title, value: currentValue)
    }
}

plotArrayInPlayground(sineWave, title: "Sine wave 1")
```

And the `Assistant Editor` shows me this:

[image]

But i want a normal graph (with axis, etc.) like this:

[image]

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it seems that Apple has removed robust graph labels in favor of unlabeled blue lines with tiny, tiny dots that a user has to click "just right" in order to display the value. From the clip I saw at the WWDC in which the speaker talks about Playground "improvements", he said that this unlabeled blue line is easier and more intuitive—in defiance of mathematics history. I can only hope that Apple will one day restore the features that they inexplicably removed (probably in an effort to make the software more stable).